# Efficient way to convert protobuf double dimension repeated value to array

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I sending data through protobuf double dimension array:

```
message IntArray{
    repeated int32 IntVal=1;
}

message DoubleDimentionIntArray{
    repeated IntArray IntArray=1;
}
```

Now, on the client side I am converting the data into double dimension array:

```
var data = xProtoClient.GetRecord(_protocolRequest).DoubleDimentionIntArray;
var intArrayList = new List<int[]>();
foreach (var arr in data.IntArray)
{
    intArrayList.Add(arr.IntVal.ToArray());
}

return intArrayList.ToArray();
```

It is not so "pretty". Is there another more efficient way to do it?

Comment: is it jagged? or rectangular? meaning: does each inner array have the same size?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be rectangular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is rectangular (comments), the efficient way to do this is to transform the data to a regular flat vector of the combined size, and essentially transmit:

```proto
message IntArray{
    repeated int32 IntVal=1 [packed=true];
    int32 Width=2;
}
```

The height is implicit by the total size divided by the width. The packed encoding is important here too, although this may now be implicit / automatic depending on the exactly tooling you're using.